# generating customer ID: prefixed with alpha characters

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm planning to make a simple helpdesk form. One of the attributes it needs is a unique number.

How can I create a unique identifier, starting with a string? Example: `KL0001` and `KL0002`

It must be a number which is unique.

Comment: Is the "KL" portion always the same?

Comment: The "KL" applies to every single CustomerID? If so, why do you need to store it? You'd no more store the name of the field in the field itself, so why store something that is the same for every single record? It looks to me like a presentation-layer issue, and you can include it on your printouts and perhaps in forms, but there seems to be no need to store it. And if it had some meaning, it shouldn't be stored in the same field with the number, anyway...

Comment: I agree with David. If the KL is used for all customer ID's there is really no need to append it to the ID in the database. Adjust the presentation layer to handle this issue rather in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a standard AutoNumber field to store the numerical portion, and then a separate Calculated column that formats the result prefixing "KL" and padding the AutoNumber field with the necessary zeros.

Example:

```
SELECT "KL" & Fmt(autonum_field, "0000") AS unique_identifier
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: I would not use an Autonumber field because if the user stars to enter the record and then cancels the autonumber value is "lost".

Comment: It is to be hoped that this works out, but over the years I have seen any number of posts where the autonumber gets revealed to the users / management and it suddenly starts meaning something and from then on life gets complicated. As a general rule, autonumbers / surrogate keys should not be shown to users: http://www.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm

Comment: @Remou - I do not disagree with you. However, I try not to introduce complexity into someone else's design if it is unclear whether or not it is called for. I, too, would shy away from using surrogate keys, but then again, I would also shy away from using Access ;)

Comment: @XSaint32: @Remou is not recommending against surrogate keys. He's just recommending rolling your own sequence for your surrogate key instead of relying on the Autonumber.

Comment: thank you all for your replies. I know this is the answer, but I don't know how to put this into a access form. But that is not your concern :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using an autonumber is, among other things, if someone starts to enter the record the autonumber is assigned.   Then, if the user cancels adding the record the autonumber value is lost.  So you are better to wait until the user finishes entering the record and in the forms AfterInsert event run the code as per the following KB article.

[ACC2000: How to Create a Multiuser Custom Counter](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;210194)

That said I'd still use an autonumber field in the table so that it's easier to work with child tables.

Comment: Yes, the OP didn't state the numbers needed to be sequential.  But it's been my experience that as soon as someone needs a custom numbering sequence they all need a solution with no gaps.  The bean counters aka accountants really like that.   Thus we also need to start thinking about flagging the transaction as deleted or inactive rather than deleting the record.

Comment: It can be a government requirement that say, invoices, should be sequential and that any gaps should be justified. In paper days, incorrectly typed invoices often had to be kept.

Comment: The OP only stated the the value be unique. You are assuming that it is a government requirement. What if the requirement is for a movie database? Do gaps matter?

Comment: Remou, it's more an accounting requirement than a government requirement.    XSaint32 like I said "it's been my experience..."

Comment: Depends where you are from. The VAT inspectors could get very touchy.